# Что обозначает слово сдынна?

Tags: этимология

Мои мать и бабушка часто употребляли слово "сдынна". Например говорили на ворох неглаженного белья "целая сдынна". Интересно происхождение этого слова.

Comment: А точно там Н удвоенное? Нехарактерно для диалектных слов . И откуда бабушка родом?

Answer (score 1):

**Здынна** упоминается в числе слов, употреблявшихся в сёлах Нижнего Прикамья, возможно, под влиянием татарского языка.

http://www.srpkzn.ru/I/wp-content/uploads/Argamak_24_media.pdf

(В. Лавров, Далёкое - близкое, литературный журнал "Аргамак", Татарстан; №1 2016 с. 216)

> В разговорной речи применялось много старых, полузабытых слов: баский
>   — красивый, баять — говорить, восетта — недавно, на днях, пошто —
>   зачем, почему, **здынна** — ерунда, нонсенс.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно знать, и как звучало, и как мама и бабушка написали бы это слово. Вероятно, что на бумаге оно выглядело бы иначе. Контекст употребления слова говорит о возможном его отношении к смысловому ряду слов с корнем ***зда*** (ПЦСС Г. Дьяченко):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]